# I have a C# switch and I need to call a method before each case returns. Is there any way I could simplify this?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have this code which I refactored to use a switch but it still looks very clumsy. Now I am looking for a way to simplify it.

```
    public async Task CheckAvailability()
    {
        switch (Settings.Mode)
        {
            case Enums.MO.Learn:
                if (await IsLearn())
                {
                    await ShowFirstMessageAsync();
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case Enums.MO.Practice:
                if (await IsPractice())
                {
                    await ShowFirstMessageAsync();
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case Enums.MO.Quiz:
                if (await IsQuiz())
                {
                    await ShowFirstMessageAsync();
                    return;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        await PickCard();
    }
```

Is there anyone that can think of a simpler way to implement this without the need for multiple calls to await ShowFirstMessageAsync?

Comment: There is not even one call to  "await NoSelected" in your Code.

Comment: By `await NoSelected` do you mean `await ShowFirstMessageAsync`?

Comment: Sorry I did a copy / paste and it looks like the copy didn't work.  Blame my MacBook Air keyboard for that ;-(

Comment: Replace the switch with a `Dictionary<Enums.MO, IAvailabilityHandler>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to use [`switch` expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions) in C# 8:

```
var shouldShowFirstMessage = Settings.Mode switch
{
    Enums.MO.Learn => await IsLearn(),
    Enums.MO.Practice => await IsPractice(),
    Enums.MO.Quiz => await IsQuiz(),
    _ => false
}
if (shouldShowFirstMessage) {
    await ShowFirstMessageAsync();
} else {
    await PickCard();
}
```

Comment: Very impressive !

Comment: Just upgraded to C# 8 and testing this out now.  I will try to use expressions more often and hopefully your answer will be a good help to others who have been wondering how they could be used.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
public async Task CheckAvailability()
{
    bool showFirstMessage = false;
    switch (Settings.Mode)
    {
        case Enums.MO.Learn:
            showFirstMessage = await IsLearn();
            break;
        case Enums.MO.Practice:
            showFirstMessage = await IsPractice();
            break;
        case Enums.MO.Quiz:
            showFirstMessage = await IsQuiz();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (showFirstMessage)
    {
        await ShowFirstMessageAsync();
        return;
    }

    await PickCard();
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Is it needed to set showFirstMessage = false; as I think the default would be false?

Comment: you could use c# switch expression to set the showFirstMessage :)

Comment: @Bambuk - can you give an example of what you mean

Comment: @Alan2 no, it would be unassigned otherwise. Sweeper's answer is better though if you can use C#8.